# Getting multiline values using regex extractor with Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to come up with regex for below response using Regex Expression Extractor,

```
while(1);
[0,'',50,0,30,[],
[[688,667,1493118907,1,'user1','Test Message 1',[]],
[687,667,1493118897,0,'user1','Test Message 1',[]],
[686,667,1493118889,0,'user1','Test Message 1',[]],
[685,667,1493118879,0,'user1','Test Message 1',[]],
[684,667,1493118869,0,'user1','Test Message 1',[]],
[683,667,1493118611,0,'user1','Test Message 1',[]]],
4,32768,50,688]
```

I am interested in getting the below fields from my response,
688,687,686,685,684,683

I am using Regular Expression - [[(.+?) , Template - $1$

I can get the first value 688 but not beyond that.

Could somebody help me with the same ?

Thanks

Comment: Try `\[([0-9]+)`

Comment: Now i get value 683,if i use reference name ${uid_g1}.I need each of those first column to pass to different requests.Should i use {uid_g2} to fetch the value of 684,{uid_g3} to fetch value of 685 etc.Also in the template should i be using $1$$2$$3$

Comment: `Match No.` must be set to a negative value to extract all matches. `$2$` can only be used if there is a second capturing group in the regex.

Comment: Thanks this works,but i am just interested in the o/p from second line i.e.,[[688,667,1493118907,1,'user1','Test Message 1',[]], and not first line [0,'',50,0,30,[], . Is it possible to omit this ?

Comment: I do not know what is dynamic or static in your input. If there is always `,`+digit after the values you need, you might try `\[([0-9]+),[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get these values : 688,687,686,685,684,683
use this regular expression **\[(\d+),\d** and template **$1$** and match number **-1** then u can use them like this:

For the first value "688" use ${uid_1}

For the second value "687" use ${uid_2} and so...

check out [Regular expression](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) from Jmeter user manual and [using regex with jmeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: No need to use a lazy quantifier with `\d`, `\d+` is enough and more efficient.